# JQuery - when a button is clicked, how do I tell the function is running/busy and how do I tell the function is done?

Tags: jquery

Say you have a script in a function and you hooked it up to the button onclick event.

I'm wondering of how do you tell a function is busy/running and how to tell it is done/completed?

Is there a flag in JQuery for that?

Thanks...

Comment: you could use some kind of website namespaced variable to keep state of the script

Comment: Use callbacks for that.

Comment: [deferred](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/),[promises](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) allow you to track the progress of functions. And here is a in-depth tutorial on both: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg723713.aspx)

Comment: David - You referring to this?   http://api.jquery.com/category/callbacks-object/

Comment: difference between callbacks and deferred??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like both followed-up comments by @David Jashi and @rusln under my original question.

Unfortunately, they didn't create an "Answer" section so I have no way to click on the green checkmark on them (in the comments) and I can only answer my question instead to close the StackOverflow question here.  :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about AJAX jQuery functions such as $.post, you have a on-success function you can assign...

```
$('#loading').fadeIn(200);
$.post('link.php', $('#form').serialize(), function(data) {
    // this will trigger when data is done retrieving
    $('#newcontent').html(data);
    $('#loading').fadeOut(200);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply keep a variable with the status of the function:

```
var myFunctionRunning;

$('#myElem').click(function () {
    myFunctionRunning = true;

    // long running stuff goes here

    myFunctionRunning = false;
});
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have a global variable to keep track of it.

Comment: @fletchsod You didn't provide any context in the question. If you want to arbitrarily check whether a function is running or not, it will have to be globally stored. If you just want to prevent the function from double-executing, you can put the variable in the function itself to limit the scope. Otherwise you can put it wherever is most appropriate based on your design.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute a function and check if it is running, then you can check the **[.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** storage associated with that element.

```
$(document).on("click.demo", "#btnRun", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var self = $(this),
      status = self.data("_status");

  if (status == "Running") return false;

  // Define the status of execution
  if(!status) self.data("_status", "Running");

  // TODO: add your code here

  // When finish, delete the flag
  self.removeData("_status");
});
```

---

Also you can create a **[closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)** (see [JavaScript: Closures](https://jherax.wordpress.com/2015/02/13/javascript-closures/))

Consider the following example: [http://jsfiddle.net/qundC](http://jsfiddle.net/qundC/3/)

```
// Creates a closure with status and the callback
var fnExecute = (function () {
    var _running = false;

    // Function returned by the closure
    return function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if(_running) {
            $('#status').text("Running...");
            return false;
        }

        _running = true;
        $('#status').text("Starts...");

        // TODO: add your code here

        // Emulates an expensive processing
        setTimeout(function () {
            _running = false;
            $('#status').text("Done!!");
        }, 5000);
    };
}());

// Assigns the function returned by the closure
$(document).on("click.demo", "#btnRun", fnExecute);
```